# Asp .net file watcher abrupt behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used file watcher to keep watch on a folder for file creation, my code is below :-

```
 _watcher = new FileWatcher();
            _watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LandingArea"];            
            _watcher.NotifyFilter =
                NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                NotifyFilters.FileName |
                NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                NotifyFilters.LastAccess;
            _watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _watcher.Created += _watcher_Created;
```

-----------------------Event Is Below----------------------

```
  private void _watcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            DataAccessLayer.InsertFileToDatabase();
        }
```

My question is i am getting 3 files at the same time and only 1 of the 3 files is inserted to the database that means file watcher has fired event only for 1file even though i have 3 files created.

Any help is appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring FileSystemEventArgs when calling InsertFileToDatabase. I suspect there might be a bug in logic inside this method.

Event args are carrying full path of the new file, as well as information what kind of change has occurred on it. I suggest you to rely on that object, rather than on custom logic.

> that means file watcher has fired event only for 1 file even though i have 3 files created.

This is only indirect conclusion and it might be wrong. I suggest you to audit event handler and track full path and change type from event args, and that will lead you to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as far as the answer is concerned i have not ignored the FileSystemEventArgs, i am using it inside the InsertFiletoDatabase method, just written snippet here its not the actual code :-

Comment: Can you audit content of event args and calls to the event handler, just to make sure how many times and with what data it fires?

Comment: Yes, i have done it and the conclusion is event is fired only once and one more thing would like to specify that the create time for all the three files is exactly same upto milliseconds.